# Why won't this regex expression match HTML tags?

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a HTML parser with python and in order to extract HTML attributes out of the tags I am using regular expressions. This is the expression I am using

```
tag_exp = r'</?(?P<name>[a-z A-Z]+) (?P<attribute>[a-z A-Z]+="[\w]+")* /?>'
matches = re.match(tag_exp, '<img src="test.jpg" alt="test">')
```

But it doesn't match anything. I have been trying to figure it out for a while now, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Python has *so many* libraries for this. Use them, they're better than a regex could ever be.

Comment: You can not parse HTML with regex. Do not even try.

Comment: Regex isn't made to scan HTML documents. That's like opening the gates to oblivion, releasing the kraken, digging up the stench... * _sic_ * Please use libraries for that like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: You are not writing a parser.

Comment: Seems like it should be easy but it's actually not even possible because HTML is not a regular language (it's technically a context-free language but that's a whole 'nother can of worms). As others have said, use a proper HTML/XML parser for this.

Comment: If you use regex you have to account for non-quoted, non-attributes. As a start, you have to capture the entire tag, then parse out attributes. But, you have to bypass comments and scripts and the like. Not really that easy, but doable. Therefore, its a multi-step process. The primary regex for tag-attributes is this `<(?:(\w+)\s+((?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+)\s*/?)>` But you have to sub-parse the attributes with another regex. I won't show the methods because it is too large, but that's what you're up against.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I am aware of the numerous libraries that are available for this. This is simply a learning experiment to see if I can do it. I am curious to know why this question has been down voted so I can refrain from making any more questions like it. Also, no one has yet to answer the question I asked, "What did I do wrong" in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup instead. Check this example.

```
import BeautifulSoup
html = '<p class="c4">SOMETEXT</p><p class="c5"></p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
print [tag.attrs for tag in soup.findAll('p') if tag.string]
```